# unkown error-not found when try to make call from linphone for android

Tags: android, linphone

whenever i try to make a call with linphone for android it pop up a error message "unkown error-not found". Help me please. I registered with free sip account from linphone's website. And in the logcat it says "Bluetooth binder is null."

Comment: Same thing, just wanted to let know, you're not alone. One day people will use open sip accounts instead of closed source services like whatsup!

Comment: yeah hope so :) And thanks for replying :)